# Android NDK sourceSets.main coundn't find jni

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental

Like above, my build.gradle file cannot sync because it could not find property "jni" on source sets "main". I'm using gradle-experimental:0.7.0.
I wan't to use Android.mk file in compilation, but i cannot set srcDirs = [].
My build.gradle:

```
model {
android {
    def globalConfiguration = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")

    compileSdkVersion = globalConfiguration.getAt("androidCompileSdkVersion")
    buildToolsVersion = globalConfiguration.getAt("androidBuildToolsVersion")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ndk"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel globalConfiguration.getAt("androidMinSdkVersion")
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel globalConfiguration.getAt("androidTargetSdkVersion")
        versionCode globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionCode")
        versionName globalConfiguration.getAt("androidVersionName")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        def commonTestDir = 'src/commonTest/java'
        test {
            java.srcDir commonTestDir
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDir commonTestDir
        }
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
}

 android.ndk {
     moduleName = 'mymodule'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into the plugin [Experimental Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental), according to it, to specify the source directory, you have to do it like so:

```
model {
    android {
        ...

        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not the way you did it. Take a look, here is the `sources` property used, but not the `sourceSets`